# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm relatively new to ReactJS and just started to make a portfolio project.
When I run the program, it doesn't show any error in the editor but shows the following error in the browser.

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `HomePage`.

Here is my **HomePage.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import Hero from '../components/Hero';
import Carousel from '../components/Carousel';

function HomePage(props) {

    return(
        <div>
            <Hero title={props.title} subTitle={props.subTitle} text={props.text} />
            <Carousel />
        </div>
    );

}

export default HomePage;
```

**Hero.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Jumbotron from 'react-bootstrap/Jumbotron';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

function Hero(props) {

    return(
        <Jumbotron className="bg-transparent jumbotron-fluid p-0">
            <Container fluid={true}>
                <Row className="justify-content-center py-5">
                    <Col md={8} sm={12}>
                        { props.title && <h1 className="display-1 font-weight-bolder">{props.title}</h1> }
                        { props.subTitle && <h3 className="display-4 font-weight-light">{props.subTitle}</h3> }
                        { props.text && <h3 className="lead font-weight-light">{props.text}</h3> }
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </Jumbotron>
    );

}
export default Hero;
```

**Carousel.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import Card from '../components/Card';

import pose1 from '../assets/images/pose1.jpg';
import pose2 from '../assets/images/pose2.jpg';
import pose3 from '../assets/images/evverest.jpg';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';

class Carousel extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    title: 'Dev Grub',
                    subTitle: 'The cookbook for developers',
                    imgSrc: pose1,
                    link: 'https://devgrub.com',
                    selected: false
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'Garrett Love',
                    subTitle: 'YouTube channel',
                    imgSrc: pose2,
                    link: 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxSITxL2JbF229OGCqieVZw',
                    selected: false
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Evverest',
                    subTitle: 'A social network for developers',
                    imgSrc: pose3,
                    link: 'https://github.com/garrettlove8/evverest',
                    selected: false
                },
            ]
        }
    }


    handleCardClick = (id, card) => {

        let items = [...this.state.items];

        items[id].selected = items[id].selected ? false : true;

        items.forEach(item => {
            if(item.id !== id) {
                item.selected = false;
            }
        });

        this.setState({
            items
        });
    }


    makeItems = (items) => {
        return items.map(item => {
            return <Card item={item} click={(e => this.handleCardClick(item.id, e))} key={item.id} />
        })
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <Container fluid={true}>
                <Row className="justify-content-around">
                    {this.makeItems(this.state.items)}
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }

}

export default Carousel;
```

The imports are absolutely correct. How do I resolve this error?

**OUTPUT/CONSOLE:**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code you have provided is complete, then it looks like you are not exporting anything in the `Hero.js` file.

Adding

```
export default Hero
```

at the end `Hero.js` and should fix the problem.

Comment: Ohh! I'm sorry, I have "export default Hero; " in Hero.js. I forgot to copy it too.

Comment: Is there a stack trace below the error in the console. If yes, please share that as well.

Comment: @HassaanTauqir I guess this won't work since this is not a valid JSX.

Comment: Yes you are right @Manan Joshi, removed the update to avoid confusion. Probably going to need stack  trace or more info on this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are passing props to `HomePage.js`, but maybe you don't have any or your props is an object i.e. `heroText={props.heroText}`and you are calling it wrong: `props.title` instead of `props.heroText.title`.

What are the props you are passing to `HomePage.js`?