# yet another Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting the following error in my react-native app. It works fine when debugging in chrome (`npm run web`) but when I generate apk it crashes on start.

It's apparently a common problem and already asked multiple time([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68409104/after-updating-expo-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-co), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60791921/error-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-components-or-a)) but none of these helped me.

I can't post the whole app here because I don't know which file causes the problem but this is the index component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import * as Device from 'expo-device';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import Home from './components/home';
import About from './components/about';
import { isWeb } from './utilities';

import rootReducer from './reducers';
import { setPushNotificationToken } from './services/identityService';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: false,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});

async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;
  if (Device.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      if (!isWeb) {
        alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
      }
      return '<error>';
    }
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
  } else {
    alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    });
  }

  return token;
}

export default function Index() {
  const [, setNotification] = useState(false);
  const notificationListener = useRef();
  const responseListener = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then((token) => {
      store.dispatch(setPushNotificationToken(token));
      // TODO: call backend to register the device token
    });

    notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
      setNotification(notification);
    });

    responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(() => {
      // TODO: call backend to notify notification was read
    });

    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
            options={{
              title: 'Overview',
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="About" component={About} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Error:

```
Exception com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
This error is located at:
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in b, stack:
Ii@35:89340
<unknown>@35:40603
Fl@35:58157
xa@35:92676
vi@35:83678
gi@35:83606
hi@35:83371
oi@35:80340
oi@-1
xt@35:27446
ni@35:77138
ji@35:91646
<unknown>@35:97778
<unknown>@348:1279
run@339:1403
runApplication@339:2420
value@61:3579
<unknown>@61:758
value@61:2582
value@61:730
value@-1
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:72)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:920)
```

[Repository](https://gitlab.com/hesamian/milwaukee-internationals-app/-/tree/d0a591f2e84b95cbcf9fc2c6c8e1d5dd23900aa2)

[Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amir734jj.milwaukeeinternationals&hl=en-US&ah=0HJQcLOAjARXpIM1-ej72eN6iBc)

Comment: Can you try one thing for me in your home index.js file don't return Drawer code return normal JSX and then check if your code works or not

Comment: @Alpha the solution was adding `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` as you suggested. [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/getting-started/)

Comment: That's greats.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a doubt that this error might have something to do with **home index.js**

Can you try one thing for me in your home **index.js** file don't return **Drawer code** return **normal JSX** and then check if your code works or not

Answer (score 0):

For the Drawer you want to use in **Home** you will need gesture handler, do you use it?